# How to restrict directory access

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have folder directory http://test.com/app/cl/login.php. If anyone tries to access app folder, it can. Please let me know how to stop them accessing it and redirect the url to http://test.com/ if anyone tries to access app folder directly. I tried to do it through htaccess but it blocks the whole website

The options I tried

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^app/ - [L,R=404] 

  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com\/app [NC,OR]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:\/\/test\.com\/$1 [L,R=301,NC] 

  Redirect 301 /app test.com
```

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\/app\/cl [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:\/\/test\.com\/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: Redirect 301 /app/cl http://www.test.com/

Comment: I tried both in htaccess but they don't work

Comment: Sorry, i have added them in code... Actually, the app is a directory which has a login page. If i use any of them, its blocking the page too. I just want it to be redirected if anyone tries to alter the url and try to access the app folder.. Thanks for your time, starkeen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rules :

```
  RewriteEngine On
  #1) redirect "/app/"
  RewriteRule ^app/?$ http://example.com/ [L,R]
  #2) redirect "/app/cl/"
  RewriteRule ^app/cl/?$ http://example.com/ [L,R]
```

You can alternatively accomplish this using the RedirectMatch directive :

```
RedirectMatch ^/app/?$ http://example.com/
RedirectMatch ^/app/cl/?$ http://example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks alot starkeen, it works... Should I use first one only as cl folder is in app folder or you would recommend to use both?

Comment: You should use both, as the first rule only redirects **/app/** it doesnt redirect **/app/cl/** .

Comment: Well,I just find a problem my friend... actually in app folder, i am running another website as cms... Now, if I use above code, its redirecting the domain assigned to cms to main website. I am hosting both website on same server... for example, I have primary domain as http://example.com/, and add on domain as http://test.com/. if I now try to open test.com, it redirects me to example.com :(